# Running Selenium with UI on Ubuntu Server to be displayed on the remote computer's display

Tags: ssh, xorg, display, selenium

I have a remote computer with Ubuntu Server 22.04 running. I have some python scripts that use Selenium. I would like Selenium to display the web browser's UI on the remote computer's VGA display.

Currently, if I run the script through `ssh -X` the UI will display on my local computer's (Ubuntu Desktop 22.04) screen, and the script runs just fine. If I try to run it through just `ssh` (without the `-X`), the python script almost immediately crashes with the error message:

```
(unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
(The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

I have tried setting the `$DISPLAY` environment variable, but that doesn't seem to change anything, and I suspect that more than that is needed because this is Ubuntu Server, so there is no desktop environment.

Is there anything I can do, short of installing a desktop environment on the remote computer?